# How to access all child elements of a GridView?

Tags: android, gridview

I have a `GridView` showing items of "icon with text overlay".
On a specific event I want to iterate all of those items and change the text. But how can I get a reference to those items outside of a `OnItemClickListener`?

Can I somehow execute something like:
`view.findAllViewById(R.id.itemtext);`? I know the findAll() does not exist.

item_view.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <ImageView />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/itemtext" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <GridView android:id="@+id/simpleGridView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Code.

```
GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.simpleGridView);
grid.setAdapter(..); //inside adapter: inflates the items by R.layout.item_view

grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView item = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemtext));
        item.setText("some click text");
    }
});
```

Question: how can I access all available `R.id.itemtext` elements, and iterate through them? Because I have no reference to them.

Comment: What you want to do if you will get all textview ref ?

Comment: notify your adapter to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Child views**

If your really want to access the `R.id.itemtext` views you could probably use the `GridView` as a `ViewGroup` (it extends it), iterate over its children and `findViewById(R.id.itemtext)` for each of them:

```
for (int i = 0; i < grid.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View child = getChildAt(i);
    View itemText = child.findViewById(R.id.itemtext);
    ...
}
```

**2. Adapter items**

But GridView is also an [AdapterView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html) and it has some handy methods like [`getFirstVisiblePosition`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getFirstVisiblePosition()), [`getLastVisiblePosition`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getLastVisiblePosition()) and [`getItemAtPosition`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getItemAtPosition(int)) and I would consider using them to get the data in the (currently visible) text views like this:

```
int first = grid.getFirstVisiblePosition();
int last = grid.getLastVisiblePosition();
for(int i=first; i<=last; ++i){
    Object item = grid.getItemAtPosition(); // You should probably cast to your adapter's item type
}
```